# How do I create a 1GB random file in Linux?

Tags: linux, dd

I am using the bash shell and would like to pipe the out of the command `openssl rand -base64 1000` to the command `dd` such as `dd if={output of openssl} of="sample.txt bs=1G count=1`. 
I think I can use variables but I am however unsure how best to do so. The reason I would like to create the file is because I would like a 1GB file with random text.

Comment: What do you want to do with that file? To check e.g. compression algorithms, use the type of data they are designed for (natural language text you can get boatloads at project Gutenberg; source code, grab e.g. the GNU, BSD, Sourceforge packages or sample github). "Real world" data is *not* random.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

`if=` is not required, you can pipe something into `dd` instead:

```
something... | dd of=sample.txt bs=1G count=1 iflag=fullblock

something... | head -c 1G > sample.txt
```

It wouldn't be useful here since `openssl rand` requires specifying the number of bytes anyway. So you don't actually need `dd` – *this* would work:

```
openssl rand -out sample.txt -base64 $(( 2**30 * 3/4 ))
```

1 gigabyte is usually 2<sup>30</sup> bytes (though you can use `10**9` for 10<sup>9</sup> bytes instead). The `* 3/4` part accounts for Base64 overhead, making the *encoded* output 1 GB.

Alternatively, you could use `/dev/urandom`, but it would be a little slower than OpenSSL:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=1G count=1 iflag=fullblock
```

I would use `bs=64M count=16` or similar, so that 'dd' won't try to use the entire 1 GB of RAM at once:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=64M count=16 iflag=fullblock
```

or even the simpler `head` tool – you don't really *need* dd here:

```
head -c 1G /dev/urandom > sample.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. A few questions, does using the command `openssl rand -base64 $(( 2**30 * 3/4 )) > sample.txt` give you a true text file? Secondly I don't quite follow the use of `bs=64M count=16`. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: I posted a question regarding compressing large files at http://superuser.com/questions/467697/why-does-a-zip-file-appear-larger-than-the-source-file-especially-when-it-is-tex and was advised that using `/dev/urandom` generates a binary file and not a true text file.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: What do you mean by a "true text file"? A file that only contains printable characters, I'm guessing? Then yes, the `-base64` option tells OpenSSL to output a "text" file.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: But beware that **random data does not compress well**, regardless of whether it is "binary" or "true text".

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Right; you would need something like `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=750M count=1 | uuencode my_sample > sample.txt`.

Comment: @Scott - Can you elaborate what that does exactly as well as why you are using a byte size of 750M and a count of 1?

Comment: @grawity - Well people keep bouncing the term "true text file" and based on my previous post it was suggested that `/dev/urandom` generates binary files. My understanding is that a text file is one with printable characters although am unsure whether ASCII characters would count. I thought `-base64` is used to convert binary data to text?

Comment: @grawity - If random data does not compress well, how can I create a file that mimics real world scenarios?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: There's no single "real world scenario", some scenarios might be dealing with gigabytes of text, others – with gigabytes of JPEGs, or gigabytes of compiled software... If you want a lot of text, download a [Wikipedia dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html) for example.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: The `dd` reads 750,000,000 bytes from `/dev/urandom` and pipes them into `uuencode`.  `uuencode` encodes its input into a form of base64 encoding (not necessarily consistent with other programs).  In other words, this converts binary data to text.  I used 750M because I trusted grawity's statement that base64 encoding expands data by 33⅓%, so you need to ask for ¾ as much binary data as you want in your text file.

Comment: @Scott: Pure Base64 always encodes 3 bytes to 4 (33.(3)%). OpenSSL's encoder splits output into 64-character lines (so about 35.4% overhead; I forgot to account for this – would be `*48/65`). UUencode uses even shorter lines and adds length prefixes, header & footer, resulting in ~40% overhead.

Comment: @Scott - That makes sense although am curious to understand why limit the count to 1?

Comment: @grawity - I am astounded by the depth of knowledge. Where are you learning all of this stuff?

Comment: @leighmcc: FYI: using `>` redirection does *not* make the writes pass through bash – it is equivalent to having the program open the file directly.

Comment: Note if it says `dd: warning: partial read (33554431 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock` it will create a *truncated file* so add the `iflag=fullblock` flag, then it works.

Answer (score 51):

Create a 1GB.bin random content file:

```
 dd if=/dev/urandom of=1GB.bin bs=64M count=16 iflag=fullblock
```

Comment: For me, `iflag=fullblock` was the necessary addition compare to other answers.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need a somewhat random file which is **not used for security related things**, like benchmarking something, then the following will be significantly faster:

```
truncate --size 1G foo
shred --iterations 1 foo
```

It's also more convenient because you can simply specify the size directly.

Answer (score 5):

Since, your goal is to create a 1GB file with random content, you could also use `yes` command instead of `dd`:

```
yes [text or string] | head -c [size of file] > [name of file]
```

Sample usage:

```
yes this is test file | head -c 100KB > test.file
```

Comment: In my mac os 100KB is not working, need to use this: `head -c 102400`

Answer (score 4):

If you want EXACTLY 1GB, then you can use the following:

```
openssl rand -out $testfile -base64 792917038; truncate -s-1 $testfile
```

The `openssl` command makes a file exactly 1 byte too big. The truncate command trims that byte off.

Comment: That extra byte is probably because of the `-base64`. Removing it will result in a file with the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a bash-script for this like here.
Get sure that you installed command 'pwgen' ... :

> #!/bin/bash
>
> touch cypher-01.txt
>
> pwgen -sy 1024512 1024 >> cypher-01.txt

... this is finish and a file is created with randomly size of 1GB text.
This takes on computer with 4 cores about ten minutes to fourteen minutes.
To read this 1GB file with cat -A  takes then about two and a half minutes.

Comment: Redirecting with `>>` or `>` will create the file if needed, `touch` is totally redundant. The whole idea of creating a script for the job seems like an unnecessary complication here, as the last command alone would suffice.

Answer (score -2):

Try this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
openssl rand -base64 1000 | dd of=sample.txt bs=1G count=1
```

This script might work as long as you don't mind using `/dev/random`.

```
#!/bin/bash
dd if=/dev/random of="sample.txt bs=1G count=1"
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend wasting `/dev/random` on this unless there's a very good reason to do so. `/dev/urandom` is much cheaper.

Comment: Also, `$var=(command)` isn't valid syntax in this context.

Comment: @grawity - When you say it isn't valid, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean exactly that – it's incorrect.

Comment: @grawity, @PeanutsMonkey: He made a typo; he meant `random=$(openssl rand -base64 1000)`.  Although I would question whether `bash` would let you assign a gigabyte-long value to a variable.  And even if you do say `random=$(openssl rand -base64 1000)`, the subsequent `if=$random` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Right. `random=<(openssl ...)` would *almost* work (if not for bash's poorly-thought-out implementation of the feature). And `dd if=<(openssl ...)` would definitely work, but then it's just exact same thing as `openssl ... | dd`