# When are bs and count settings for dd wrong?

Tags: filesystems, dd, filesystem-corruption

(By wrong I mean "will break things".)

Suppose we're about to use `dd`. We've chosen a valid set of `if`, `of`, and possibly `seek` and `skip`. We've carefully ensured that the command will not write past our intended output region.

How can we now subtly break things by choosing a bad combination of `bs` and `count`? How would we know?

The reason I ask is that there seem to be magic preferred values that show up. For example, in this question about generating a random 1G file, the first two answers use `if=/dev/urandom`, `of=sample.txt`, `bs=64M`, and `count=16`.

[How do I create a 1GB random file in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/470949/146041)

Of course these aren't the only valid settings but both answers used these settings, suggesting that this choice is particularly good and reasonable. Especially in a case like this where there's no filesystem or even physical disk, it's not clear to me if a choice of settings could be wrong -- not just inefficient, but *wrong*. My guess is that `dd` must write an integral number of blocks at a time so as `bs` increases so does memory usage and these values only affect performance.

The example is only an example and not something I'm specifically concerned with so go ahead and address cases where what's being copied has a filesystem.

Using dd is always a frightening leap of faith for me.

Comment: Its just some personally preference. The bs value can't be too small or there will be serious performance hit -- random/4K performance is always much slower than sequential, so we need to make bs value large enough to be sequential. Otherwise there isn't much difference: bs=64M count=16, bs=16M count=64, or bs=1M count=1024.

Comment: That is what I suspect and if I'd be plenty happy to accept an answer to that effect coming from someone who feels confident it and can briefly explain why. To try to be more specific about my concerns, when would dd corrupt a filesystem by reading or writing "sliced" filesystem blocks? Would it be readily apparent if this happened?

Comment: There is a difference when using old tape drives, but today, at least for files, there is no difference in final result. For (modern) raw devices, I would assume the same but can't be 100% sure.

Comment: @Chris.C I certainly can't ask for 100% certainty, one can't *prove* a negative after all. I just want to know if there's something I'm totally oblivious to. I don't use `dd` too often but when I do the stakes are high and it's scary! It sounds like this is an area of your expertise. Feel free to answer.

Comment: imho, you can't break things when of is a file...when of is a device, do you really care the original content? the worst scenario is writing again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Help! `dd` is scary!

You are not alone. From [tips for Linux](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/036.html):

> The ' dd ' command is one of the original Unix utilities and should be in everyone's tool box... Some people believe dd means "Destroy Disk" or "Delete Data" because if it is misused, a partition or output file can be trashed very quickly. Since dd is the tool used to write disk headers, boot records, and similar system data areas, misuse of dd has probably trashed many hard disks and file systems.

But worry ye not. Once you learn of its intricacies you'll be invoking `dd` with the calm grace of a rodeo cowboy.

### Will it break? What's this `count`ing `bs`?

Let's deal with the first question first.

> How can we now subtly break things by choosing a bad combination of `bs` and `count`? How would we know?

If you mean 'unintended consequences' by 'break', then just by specifying them, in theory. What do I mean by that? Well, lets say you want to copy `image.img` onto an SD card located at `/dev/sdc`. So you match the parameters in your example:

```
# dd if=/home/someone/image.img of=/dev/sdc bs=64M count=16
```

Should be fine to reuse those settings right? Let's just wait for `dd` to finish... now, what's it saying?

```
16+0 records in
16+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 34.1303 s, 31.5 MB/s
```

Only 1.1 GB copied! But `image.img` is **2GB** or so, I want the whole thing copied! By telling `dd` to copy 16 lots of 64M (where M=1024*1024, incidentally) you've specified a size. You would know by the status output. If you want to copy the whole file, either match the size with `bs` and `count`; or just omit those entirely:

```
# dd if=/home/someone/image.img of=/dev/sdc
4364864+0 records in
4364864+0 records out
2234810368 bytes (2.2 GB) copied, 45.9502 s, 48.6 MB/s
```

What happens if we get really naughty and tell `dd` to copy more data than is available?

```
# dd if=/home/someone/image.img of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=4096
2131+1 records in
2131+1 records out
2234810368 bytes (2.2 GB) copied, 77.9768 s, 28.7 MB/s
```

Ah, `dd` only copies as many bytes as it receives. That's handy.

### Monitoring `dd`

Speaking of status output, `dd` (GNU variant) respects and responds to the INFO signal `SIGUSR1`:

```
# echo "In another terminal or TTY"
# pkill -USR1 -n -x dd
# echo "Printed to stdout on the terminal/tty running dd:"
534+0 records in
534+0 records out
559939584 bytes (560 MB) copied, 1.68414 s, 332 MB/s
```

Handy for keeping an eye on a transfer which is slow or you expect to hang for some reason. Pairs nicely with `watch`, but be sure to give `watch` a reasonably long interval time.

### Does `dd` have any other options I should know about?

`dd` does indeed have other options, but in most cases if you need to use them you will know what they do. Still, a few examples might give you an idea:

- `conv=CONVS`: convert the input as per one or more conversion options
- `seek=N` and `skip=N`: skip N [obs|ibs]-sized blocks at start of [output|input]
- `status=X`: (suppress output) either `noxfer` or `none`

### I'm feeling much better about `dd` now!

Great! In no time you will be sending a bootable image across the internet to be written straight to a microSD card using a combination of `dd` and `ssh`.

### But what does the `dd` acronym actually stand for?

A good last question. For that question and any others like it, I'll refer you to the [jargon file entry for `dd`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/dd.html).

---

Feel encouraged to ask for clarification if anything is more opaque than it should be!

Answer (score -3):

Your question is self-contradictory:

> We've carefully ensured that the command will not write past our intended output region.
>
> How can we now subtly break things by choosing a bad combination of bs and count? How would we know?

If you chose a bad combination of `bs` and `count`, the only thing you could break is writing past your intended output region (or not reaching it, which I consider the same issue)

If you have carefully ensured that the command will not write past your intended output region, you cannot break things because you've already ensured your combination of `bs` and `count` isn't bad. The two cannot occur simultaneously. Similarly, if you've not understood the `bs` and `count` parameters, you can't possibly have carefully ensured your output region is correct.

That said, the `bs` parameter is largely a performance tuning parameter. If you specify a `bs` smaller than the physical sector size *and* you are reading/writing in raw mode, or another completely out-of-whack value, `dd` will simply, and not in a subtle manner ('Abort: I/O error!'). Otherwise, things will just be slow.