# Why is text files compressed folder bigger than the original folder?

Tags: python, zip

I am compressing 3 text files around 80 bytes each by a python code. I start with the following size of the folder:

[image]

And when I compress it, it's the following size:

[image]

It appears to be bigger than the original folder. Isn't it supposed to be compressed? The 3 files are some basic NotePad text files.

> Why is the compressed folder bigger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a zip file appear larger than the source file especially when it is text?](https://superuser.com/questions/467697/why-does-a-zip-file-appear-larger-than-the-source-file-especially-when-it-is-tex)

Comment: Files smaller than a certain size occupy space in the disk MFT (master file table) along with their file descriptors rather than occupying clusters on disk. Once you go to compress it then the data gets pushed out into actual clusters and take up "real" disk space. https://superuser.com/questions/1185461/maximum-size-of-file-that-can-be-stored-entirely-in-ntfs-master-file-table-mft . Zip files have headers and may store filenames, crc and other properties uncompressed which for small files may actually be larger than the data itself